# chrome guest permantly on

Tags: user-profiles, private-browsing, guest-account

I would like chrome to always start in guest mode. NOT  --profile-directory="Guest Profile" which gives me options. 
ALWAYS in guest mode and not sharing profiles.

incredibly frustrating and annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest one can come to a true guest session is by adding to the Chrome
start icon the two parameters of `-incognito --bwsi`.

From [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) :

> **--bwsi**    Indicates that the browser is in "browse without sign-in" (Guest session) mode. Should completely disable extensions, sync and bookmarks.